# Blackberry ListField: how to add Listener for list row click

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, listfield

Suppose i had a Screen class that has 10 ListField:

```
Vector v_prj_title,v_prj_mgr 

// v_prj_title contains name of projects

// v_prj_mgr contains name of the project_manager of  v_prj_title sequentially.

//Vector send_vector

//ListField myList

//ListCallBack callback

//It is clear from the code that in myList, I m inserting a vector send_vector ie  callback.insert(send_vector,i), which contains 2 strings collected one from v_prj_title and other from v_prj_mgr.


for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    myList.insert(i);
    t1 = v_prj_title.elementAt(i).toString();
    send_vector = new Vector(2);
    send_vector.addElement(t1);
    t2 = v_prj_mgr.elementAt(i).toString();
    send_vector.addElement(t2);
    callback.insert(send_vector,i);
}
```

Now I'm getting confused how to add eventListener to particular ListField, e.g. suppose if I click the 3rd ListField,(suppose this is the displayed data below) a bitmap picture should be displayed in the 3rd ListField and the name of the project (Project_Social_Meeting) and project_manager (Tom Clerk) should be inserted into database (SQlLite)

```
1. a. Project_Chat_Master( project name)

   b. Vyom Ryan (project manager)

2. a. Project_Online_Gaming

   b. Vivek Roy

3. a. Project_Social_Meeting

   b. Tom Clerk  
      .
      .
      etc.....
```

Comment: Do you actually mean a ListField with 10 rows in it?

Comment: yes i mean that only, where in every list field there are 2 strings to be displayed (project_name, project_manager) which is inserted with the help of vector.. callback.insert(send_vector,i);

Answer (score 1):

create a CustomField/Manager depending on your requirement.(which may contain images/strings/...)

then add them to the callback method

Ex:

---

step:1

```
//creating a custom field 
class MYListFieldItem extends Field
{
//@override
paint(graphics g)
{
g.drawbitmap(bitmap,0,0);
g.drawtext(string,bitmap.getwidth()+5<padding>,Math.min(bitmap.getHeight(),getFont().getHeight()));

//@override
layout(....)
{
setExtent(Math.min(width,bitmap.getwidth()+padding+getfont.getadvance(stringtext)),
Math.min(height,Math.min(bitmap.getHeight,getFont().getHeight())));
}
}
```

---

step-2:
//create list items

```
MYListFieldItem [] fields[] = new MYListFieldItem [<numOfListItems>];
for(int i=0;i<fields.size;i++)
{
_callback = new MyListFieldCallBack();
_callback.insert(fields[i],i);
}
```

---

step-3:

```
//set listeners
mylistFielditem[i].setchangeListener(new fieldchangeListener(){
fieldChanged(field)
{
//do your action here.
});
```

---

```
//TIP: if the fields are just strings,
//@override
navigationclick()
{
if(status == keypadlistener.status_fourway)
{
MYListFieldItem  fld = (ListField)getLiefFieldwithFocus();
//do your coding 

}
}
```